# Change pages by swiping in React

Tags: reactjs, touch, react-router, swipe

Is there a way to swipe between pages in react?

Something like: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-page-transitions but using swipe as a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

For actual routing on page swipe, you would have to look at the routing library you use.

However if you want a quick one inside of a route, you can use a `pagingEnabled` attribute on a `<ScrollView>`:

```
<ScrollView horizontal pagingEnabled>
    <View>page 1</View>
    <View>page 2</View>
</ScrollView>
```

edit: my mistake, you are asking in react, i got confused by your react-native tag. please remove that if you do not want a react-native reply